# Android IntentReceiver never receives custom intent from WidgetProvider

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-widget

(This is my first SE question ever, but I've relied heavily on this site for it's fantastic community as I've bumbled around learning Java and Android!)

I'm creating an Android widget that (for the time being) has only one button that functions as a two-sided dice. Eventually this widget will support all major RPG dice sizes (d6, d8, d20, etc), but for now I'm just trying to get the intent/receiver system working.

Currently nothing happens when I hit the d2 button in my widget. So far as I can tell by debugging my custom intent is fired, but the onReceive in my IntentReceiver never catches it. Any assistance you can provide would be much appreciated!

Here is my WidgetProvider:

```
    public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
      public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
          int[] appWidgetIds) { 

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnReset, buildButtonPendingIntent(context));
        Log.e(null, "Setup remote views & Onclick");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        pushWidgetUpdate(context, remoteViews);
    }

    public static PendingIntent buildButtonPendingIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("ca.sulli.rpgdicewidget.intent.action.D2");
        Log.e(null, "Setting new ButtonPendingIntent");
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    public static void pushWidgetUpdate(Context context, RemoteViews remoteViews) {
        Log.e(null, "Updating widget!");
        ComponentName myWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        manager.updateAppWidget(myWidget, remoteViews); 
    }  
}
```

And here is my receiver:

```
public class MyWidgetIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e(null,"Checking intent by receiver");
        if(intent.getAction().equals("ca.sulli.rpgdicewidget.intent.action.D2")){
            Log.e(null,"Correct intent received!");
            updateWidgetPictureAndButtonListener(context);
        }
    }

    private void updateWidgetPictureAndButtonListener(Context context) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
        Log.e(null,"Updating text since the intent was received!");
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.txtResult, "Intent Received! ");

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnD2, MyWidgetProvider.buildButtonPendingIntent(context));

        MyWidgetProvider.pushWidgetUpdate(context.getApplicationContext(), remoteViews);
    }
}
```

And for completions' sake, my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ca.sulli.rpgdicewidget"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
         <receiver android:name="MyWidgetProvider" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="ca.sulli.rpgdicewidget.intent.action.D2" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the appwidget-provider:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:minWidth="200dp" android:minHeight="70dp" android:initialLayout="@layout/main" android:updatePeriodMillis="30000">
</appwidget-provider>
```

Many thanks for any help provided, and many thanks for the help this community has already provided for me by answering so many other questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see anywhere in your code where you are using the PendingIntent that you have created, you can use the alarmmanager to schedule a message, presumably immediately, using code like this:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (i * 1000), pendingIntent);
```

Broadcast messages are quite complex though, so you may want to weigh up if you want to use them, you could consider using a regular intent and `context.sendBroadcast` instead

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I hadn't considered that, so I'll give it a try.